# How to combine DateTime when Date is DateTime and Time is string in c#

Tags: datetime

I have a date in a format like 2010-06-25 12:00:00 AM and string with a value 01:15 PM.
How can I combine this Date and Time in a single DateTime object in C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first DateTime is dt1 and the second casted into a DateTime object dt2. You can do something like this.

```
var resultantDt=new DateTime(dt1.Year, dt1.Month, dt1.Day, dt2.Hour, dt2.Minute, dt2.Second);
```

Not sure if this is the best way :)

Comment: How can I cast 01:15 PM string to DateTime. Make sure the time in string is in 12 hours format ?

Comment: `DateTime dt2=Convert.ToDateTime("01:15 PM");
 Console.WriteLine(dt2); //this will print 3/10/2013 1:15:00 PM`

Answer (score 2):

public void Combine(DateTime date, DateTime time)
{
   return date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
}